# Userscript. Сохранение изменений

Tags: javascript, userjs

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу **userscript**. Внедряю ***HTML блок***, с несколькими переключателями. И возникла задача сохранять какие-либо  константы, что бы после перезагрузки страницы все переключатели находились в измененном пользователем состоянии, типа ф-ция: *on/off*.

Есть способы сделать это без ***cookie*** или ***спец. ф-ций GM*** ?

Comment: [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: В чем прикол писать ф-ция вместо функция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант Web Storage-http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage.
Есть и другие способы но они сложнее.